# How to upload files from C# in ASP.NET to SharePoint Online library

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, asp.net

What's the best way to go about uploading files to SP Online from C# ASP.NET Solution

Thanks

Comment: Could you please check this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/246034/sharepoint-365-upload-file-to-subfolder-list-with-net-c-csom

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is as below(make use of postman tool):

- Create **client ID** and **client secret**  SharePoint online site.
- if you don't have postman tool download and install it.
- Do a sample upload operation to SharePoint online library using the postman tool.
- Extract the C# equivalent code from the postman tool, this code will be generated automatically by the tool.
- Plugin this C# code in your actual project.
- Done

Details steps are here :

[In 4 steps access SharePoint online data using postman tool](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/in-4-steps-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-tool/)

Similar thread is discussed here :

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/273657/85808